# List all archive files

Tags: 12.04, files, archive

How can I get the list of all archive files in a folder recursively without knowing the file extension?

Comment: What so you call "archive" files?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `file` utility to attempt to classify a file based on a sequence of filesystem tests, magic tests, and language tests - for example

```
$ file pynauty-0.5.tar 
pynauty-0.5.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

$ file opencv-2.4.10.zip
opencv-2.4.10.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

When run on compressed files, the default is just to report that it contains "compressed data", but you can alter that behaviour using the `-z` switch

```
 -z, --uncompress
         Try to look inside compressed files.
```

i.e.

```
$ file -b octave-4.0.0.tar.gz 
gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Tue May 26 12:35:47 2015, max compression
```

whereas

```
$ file -zb octave-4.0.0.tar.gz 
POSIX tar archive (gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Tue May 26 12:35:47 2015, max compression)
```

Based on that, you could try running `file -zb` within a `find` command, and `grep`ing for the word "`archive`": something like

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -zb "$1" | grep -q "archive"' _ {} \; -print
```

The `-b` switch prevents false matches on the file name.

Comment: The command `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -zb "$1" | grep -q "archive"' _ {} \;` shows nothing with `XZ compressed data`.

Comment: @A.B. it works for me on .xz compressed tar archives so I guess it's a matter of semantics: does the OP want *archives* (whether compressed or not) or *compressed files* (whether - strictly - archives or not)

Comment: I don't know, he mentioned this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file

Comment: Anyway, it's a good answer +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file type with this command for an archive/file without an extension:

```
% file tar-latest            
tar-latest: XZ compressed data
```

or an other example:

```
% file foo          
foo: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

To list all archives

```
find . -type f -exec file {} \; | awk '/compressed|archive/'
```

---

*Example*

```
% find . -type f -exec file {} \; | awk '/compressed|archive/'
./tar-latest: XZ compressed data
./foo: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Comment: @ScepticalJule Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply, how to copy those files into a directory ?